# Finding all stable matchings in stable marriage problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-hard, combinatorics, matching

I need to find an algorithm for a modified version of the [stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem). In particular, I need to find all possible stable matchings and not only one (unlike what the Gale-Shapley algorithm does). The only solution I have is to recursively enumerate all the possible matchings, discarding the recursive branches which do not satisfy the conditions. This algorithm has a complexity of **O(n!)**, with n being the number of items in each set.

I found this [similar question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5619/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-stable-marriages-for-an-instance-of-the-stable-mar) that shows that the upper bound to the number of solutions is exponential. Is there any better algorithm than the one I have so far?

In the context of similar questions, this [paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0216010) by Gusfield comes up. However, it solves a different problem.